# How to scrape the value between > and < using selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Normally I use tools like "find_element_by_id" to search for values that are within the "<>"

So how can I extract the value "Fantasy Flight Games" between the > < here?

[image]

Comment: You could use a simple regex pattern but it won't be perfect (`r'^<.*?>(.*?)</.*?>$'`. Parsing HTML/XML tags is really best done by a dedicated parser (see: lxml for python).

Comment: You either find the element using XPath or its class or css and then get the text. What is the issue in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple locator you can use any of these

as per your html u can use

Using xpath

```
//span[@class="a-size-small-a-color-secondary"]
```

or

```
//span[contains(text(),"Fantasy Flight Games")]
```

For getting text you can use `.text` method

use like this

```
Fantas_text=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class="a-size-small-a-color-secondary"]").text
print(Fantas_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`find_element_by_tag_name,find_element_by_class_name ,find_element_by_css_selecto`r etc.

just go though with official docs.

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0):

Using css selector.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[class="a-size-small a-color-secondary"]').text
```